# Can I use shouldInterceptRequest to block a particular call in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I used the following code

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
    alertsavedinternal(); //display an alert
    Log.d("DEBUG", "Should intercept request" +url); 
    //log the url to console in debug mode.
    return null;
}
```

However, while the alert is displayed my console also prints the log, besides which the url is also loaded in the background. How can I stop the url from loading?

Please correct my understanding of this function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you return null in `shouldInterceptRequest`, it means that the WebView will continue to load the resource as usual.

This is why you see the URL still being loaded.

In order to intercept and block the call, you need to return your own (Non-null) data instead.