# Prevent data from loading using shouldInterceptRequest

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

While this has been asked several times, the only question that really relates to my issue is this ([Can I use shouldInterceptRequest to block a particular call in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044554/can-i-use-shouldinterceptrequest-to-block-a-particular-call-in-android)), but it was asked more than 3 years ago and eventually got no replies.

The request I'm trying to block is a POST request, so the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method is unable to intercept it.

After a button is clicked, the webview loads an URL that contains the following string: "androidBundleId_********".

I need to block this request and redirect users to the Play Store (but I know how to do this!)

The problem is that the return type of the shouldInterceptRequest method is **WebResourceResponse** *(oh, how I wish it was boolean!*). Therefore, I must return at least a blank WebResourceResponse.

I don't want to, as everything that is inside the WebResourceResponse gets loaded in my app. I just want the webview to intercept the request and **block it**.

The app should keep showing the same webpage, no data should be loaded, other than the Play Store intent.

I'm posting only the relevant part of my code.

```java
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
    if(url.contains("androidBundleId_")){
        String bundleID = url.substring(url.indexOf("androidBundleId_")+"androidBundleId".length()+1, url.length());
        try {
            getContext().startActivity(new Intent
                    (Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + bundleID)));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            getContext().startActivity(new Intent
                    (Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + bundleID)));
        }

        // I'D LIKE TO RETURN NOTHING HERE !!!
    }
    return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
}
```

I know this signature is deprecated, but I'm building an app with minSdk 16, therefore I can only use this one and not the one accepting Request as  second parameter.

Do you have any workaround? Note that I cannot change the webpage containing the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no chance to do what I've been asking for, we changed the whole application logic and eventually switched to WebChromeClient. It handles links / intents automatically

Comment: Do you know what is the equivalent of `WebResourceResponse` class? I mean something which works like `shouldInterceptRequest` but returns nothing. What is the exact solution to your problem?

Comment: May I ask how you eventually used the WebChromeClient to block a resource request? It's not obvious from the API.