# Intercept requests from WebView in WebChromeClient

Tags: android, webchromeclient

I have a question related to this one: [Prevent data from loading using shouldInterceptRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42387313/prevent-data-from-loading-using-shouldinterceptrequest)

I know I need to use `WebChromeClient` now but I have no idea which method in this class is an equivalent to the `shouldInterceptRequest`. Is that another special class for it or any of the `WebChromeClient` methods are made for this? I tried with `onPermissionRequest()` but I got the feeling it's not made for this.

This is what I want to achieve, open a link in an external browser application:

```
Uri webpage = Uri.parse(request.getUrl().toString());
Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
webIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PackageManager packageManager = view.getContext().getPackageManager();
List activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities( webIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_ALL);
boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
if(isIntentSafe) view.getContext().startActivity(webIntent);
```

I suppose I just need to put this code into the proper method.